# Finding a Closed Form

Tags: induction, closed-form

Find a closed form for

$$S_n = 1 \cdot 1! + 2 \cdot 2! + \ldots + n \cdot n!.$$
for integer $n \geq 1.$ Your response should have a factorial.

Another induction problem, I tried some examples but they didn't really tell me anything.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^nkk!=(n+1)!-1$$

Comment: Thanks, Jan Eerland!  Your answer is accepted(since I can't accept a comment).

Comment: Now you can, but I did not prove it that's why I used a comment

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, i707107!  Duplicates are often hard to find.

Comment: No problem. The answer is proved in detail in the linked one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^nkk!=(n+1)!-1$$

(Now you can accept my answer :) )